# Simplify Vuex modules access

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

Is there any way we can simplify Vuex modules access?

From this:

```
this.$store.dispatch('moduleA/save')
this.$store.getters['moduleB/someGetter']
```

To this:

```
this.$store.moduleA.dispatch('save')
this.$store.moduleB.getters['someGetter']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked into the `map*` helpers? They allow you to import state, getters, mutations and actions directly onto your component as regular properties.

```es6
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState('moduleB', [
      'someGetter'
    ])
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapActions('moduleA', [
      'save'
    ]),

    test() {
      // Same as this.$store.dispatch('moduleA/save')
      this.save()

      // Same as this.$store.getters['moduleB/someGetter']
      this.someGetter
    }
  }
}
```

Other than that, the syntax you propose isn't possible, but there's nothing stopping you from writing your own helper functions to ease its usage.

If you *really* want your proposed syntax, you can hack it like this (untested):

```js
function createModuleProxy(store, module) {
  return {
    state: new Proxy({}, {
      get(target, prop) {
        return store.state[module][prop]
      },
      set(target, prop, value) {
        store.state[module][prop] = value
        return true
      },
    }),
    getters: new Proxy({}, {
      get(target, prop) {
        return store.getters[module + '/' + prop]
      },
    }),
    dispatch(mutation, payload) {
      return store.dispatch(module + '/' + mutation, payload)
    },
    commit(action, payload) {
      return store.commit(module + '/' + action, payload)
    }
  }
}

store.moduleA = createModuleProxy(store, 'moduleA')
store.moduleB = createModuleProxy(store, 'moduleB')

store.moduleA.dispatch('save')
store.moduleB.getters['someGetter']
```